# ¿Cómo puedo añadir una linea horizontal en las gráficas de google? (Google Charts)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Tengo una gráfica creada a partir de una serie de números. Quiero añadir un par de líneas horizontales fijas (por ejemplo, al 80) y otra inclinada (para la tendencia). Quiero que se vea la leyenda indicando qué es cada línea.

El código que tengo es así, donde se muestra la serie de números:

```
function drawChart() {

//cargamos nuestro array $datos creado en PHP para que se puede utilizar en JavaScript
var cargaDatos = <?php echo json_encode($datos); ?>;
var datosFinales = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(cargaDatos);
var options = {
    title: 'Rendiment',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }  
};
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
chart.draw(datosFinales, options);
}
```

Y se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me funciona ningún código para dejar lo que hay y añadir las líneas que os comento.

¿Qué debo hacer?

Comment: aqui tienes un eejemplo de lineas horizontales... es lo que pides? http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/W67qU/

Comment: @lois6b: Me parece que no exactamente. Requiere una línea y otra es una línea de tendencias.

Answer (score 1):

Para poner varios tipos de representación de datos en una gráfica usa "[Combo Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)". Si dejas que Google Charts calcule la tendencia por tí, pasa tres columnas de datos, el eje horizontal, el valor de principal y el valor de la línea fija. Para la tendencia agrega `trendlines`y sus parámetros a `options`.

Ejemplo:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Tiempo');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Rendimiento Real');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Referencia');

      data.addRows([
        [0, 0, 20],    [1, 10, 20],   [2, 23, 20],  [3, 17, 20],   [4, 18, 20],  [5, 9, 20],
        [6, 11, 20],   [7, 27, 20],  [8, 33, 20],  [9, 40, 20],  [10, 32, 20], [11, 35, 20]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Tiempo'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rendimiento'
        },
        legend: 'bottom',
        seriesType: 'area',
        series: {1: {type: 'line'}},
        trendlines: {
          0: {type: 'linear', color:"grey", opacity: 1}
        }
      };
      
 
      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```